# Convert spark RDD of tuples into numpy arrays

Tags: python, pyspark

if my RDD is like this:

```
(key (date, value), (date, value), (date, value))
```

how can I convert it to

```
(key (Numpy.Array(date), Numpy.Array(value)))
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to reshape `(date, value)` pairs:

```
>>> xs = (("x1", 1), ("x2", 2), ("x3", 3))
>>> zip(*xs)
[('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Adding map or comprehensions solves `(Numpy.Array(date), Numpy.Array(value))` part and the rest is rather straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ("foo",
        (datetime.date(2010, 01, 01),  1.0),
        (datetime.date(2011, 02, 10),  2.0),
        (datetime.date(2012, 03, 10),  3.0)
    ),
    ("bar",
        (datetime.date(2000, 04, 01),  14.0),
        (datetime.date(2001, 05, 10),  15.0),
        (datetime.date(2002, 06, 10),  16.0 )
    ), 
])

rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(np.array(_) for _ in zip(*x[1:]))))
```

Comment: But, to use zip function, you have to send all data to same node, using collect, isn`t it? Is there an alternative parallel algorithm?

Comment: No, there is no need to collect unless I've misunderstood an input format. Is it something different than the `rdd` from my answer?